# File not found in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

**Title: Issue accessing certificate files in Azure with C# code**

**Description:**
I have a C# code that works perfectly in my local development environment, but it encounters issues when deployed to Azure.

Specifically, the code **cannot find the Cert directory and the necessary certificate files**. However, I have confirmed that **the directory and files are indeed present** in the Azure environment.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```cs
public void OnPost()
{
    var clientCertificate = new SwishApi.Models.ClientCertificate()
    {
        CertificateFilePath = "Cert//Swish_Merchant_TestCertificate_1234679304.p12",
        Password = "swish"
    };

    string certificatePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Cert\\Swish_Merchant_TestSigningCertificate_1234679304.p12";
    var payoutClient = new SwishApi.PayoutClient(clientCertificate, "https://eofvqci6optquip.m.pipedream.net", "1234", "1234679304", true, SwishApi.Environment.Emulator);

    string instructionUUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").ToUpper();

    // Anropa MakePayoutRequest med formulärvärden.
    var response = payoutClient.MakePayoutRequest(PayoutTo, Personnummer, Amount, Message, instructionUUID, "7d70445ec8ef4d1e3a713427e973d097", new SwishApi.Models.ClientCertificate() { CertificateFilePath = certificatePath, Password = "swish" });
}
```

Comment: If the runtime tells you a file doesn't exist, it almost certainly does not exist at the time your code tries to access it. So if you still say, the file exist, you are most certainly looking at a different location than your code... have you verified, that `Environment.CurrentLocation` resolves to the path you think it does?

Comment: is there any update on this question?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't reproduce your issue, but I'm afraid we could check the file path first. I test with code below.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var rootRoute = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    try {
        var route = rootRoute + "\\Cert\\myfile.txt";
        var content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(route);
        ViewData["fileContent"] = content;
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ViewData["fileContent"] = "exception when read the file";
    }
    ViewData["CurrentDirectory"] = rootRoute;
    return View();
}

<div>@ViewData["CurrentDirectory"]</div>
<div>@ViewData["fileContent"]</div>
```

When I test locally, I create a folder Cert and add the txt file inside it,

[image]

the value of `Environment.CurrentDirectory` is my project path which is `C:\workspaces\xxx\WebAppMvc\WebApp2`, but if I published it to Azure web app, the value changed to `C:\home\site\wwwroot`. I checked in kudu(websitename.scm.azurewebsites.net), I didn't have Cert folder which I had in my project. So I created the folder manually alone with the file as well. Then my code worked.

[image]
[image]